# Cannot see C# xml doc strings in my referenced assemblies

Tags: c#, documentation

I write xml doc strings for all of my classes, e.g.:

```
/// <summary>
/// Executes things
/// </summary>
public class ThingExecutor { }
```

But I've just realised that the xml documentation string is only visible when that assembly is loaded into my current solution. If I reference that assembly from another project then the those xml strings are not present.

How do I make those strings visible from within other projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

build with xml-file

goto Project-Properties --> Build

Check the *XML-documentation file*-checkbox.

This will generate an xmlfile with the comments. If you reference the dll in some other project, and you place the xmlfile in the same directory as the dll, Visual Studio will read the xml-comments from the xmlfile.